# Поиск View при инициализации класса

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет. Пишу отдельный класс, в который надо будет передать экземпляр активности, в нем будет происходить поиск View.

```
class BottomNavigation(activity: MainActivity) {
    private val navigationView: View

    init {
        navigationView = activity.findViewById....
    }
}
```

Но переменную IDE подчёркивает желтым и советует соединить декларацию и инициализацию. Но таким образом наверное View будет найдена из несуществующего пока экземпляра активити, что приведёт к NPE? Или нет? Как это сделать лучше?

В классе будут методы, которые будут использовать View

В Java такая ситуация не вызывала бы никаких предупреждений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вьюшка не будет найдена пока не вызван `setcontentview` в активити, так что создавать инстанс класса стоит после вызова этого метода.

Если хочется создать инстанс класса заранее, то можно сделать так:

```
class BottomNavigation() {
    private lateinit var navigationView: View

    fun initViews(activity: MainActivity) {
        navigationView = activity.findViewById....
    }
}
```

и в активити:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.myscreen)
  bottomNavigation.initViews(this)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, понятно ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Но таким образом наверное View будет найдена из несуществующего пока экземпляра активити, что приведёт к NPE?

Как это? У вас же в параметре конструктора передается `activity`, значит экземпляр уже будет существовать.

> Но переменную IDE подчёркивает желтым и советует соединить декларацию и инициализацию.

Правильно всё IDE предлагает. Ваш код вполне можно переписать так:

```
class BottomNavigation(activity: MainActivity) {
    private val navigationView: View = activity.findViewById....
}
```

Здесь инициализация переменной произойдет при вызове конструктора (создании объекта) уже с переданным параметром `activity`.

Единственное, как правильно указал **Николай Конорев**, что главное чтобы это происходило после вызова метода `setContentView` иначе ваш `findViewById` просто ничего не найдет и вернет `null`.